# Apple receipt : Convert hours to NSDate

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter, receipt

I got a receipt from Apple to verify the validity of the non-renewable subscription in-app purchase in my app.
But Apple sends me hours like this : 2015-11-16 07:19:21 America/Los_Angeles

And I don't know if it's possible to convert that string date with an NSDateFormatter(), I search on the web, but I found nothing, and I tried many times to do it myself with no result.

It is possible to convert this date (2015-11-16 07:19:21 America/Los_Angeles) to an NSDate() with an NSDateFormatter() ?

What can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
NSString *time = @"2015-11-16 07:19:21 America/Los_Angeles";

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"YYYY-MM-dd HH-mm-ss Z";


NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [time substringToIndex:19], [[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:[time substringFromIndex:20]] abbreviation]]];
```

And the result is :

2015-11-16 15:19:21 +0000